# black screen flicker after starting QT linux application?

Tags: qt, framebuffer, imx6

I used embedded linux (imx6q) with eglfs.

Framebuffer is drawing black screen while starting Qt application.
Simple application is black for 1sec under. Heavy application is for 4~5sec.
This happens only once when first QT run.

How to prevent qt from drawing to black? I can modify kernel or QT sources.
i am looking for qt and kernel source (related framebuffer blank, switch mode).
but, i have no idea. help me.

I already posted it on the qt forum, but there is no response.

Additional edits>

I think it only happens where using Linux framebuffer.
And it seems that the QT framework takes time to load the first one-time QML modules into the system.
After that, It use cached ones, so I wonder if there is flickr for a very short period of time.

The unavoidable loading time is fine.
But I want to prevent the QT system from erasing the framebuffer in black.

Comment: It would be nice to have a small example of the code that produces this behavior. Without *anything*, it becomes difficult for anyone to comment on what might be causing this behavior and how to address this problem, (except speculating that you do this or you can try that).

Comment: @Joey Mallone, yes. i just run qt5 default example. for example 'designer'.<br/> or simple application is below.
<br/>
`import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: page
    width: 320; height: 480
    color: "lightgray"

    Text {
        id: helloText
        text: "Hello world!"
        y: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}`

Comment: It does not seem like a good way,
Solved, not running FB_ACTIVATE_NOW in kernel 
 drivers/video/fbdev/core/fbmem.c